# Check if Elements in a list are 1 above or below each other

Tags: common-lisp

I am making a LISP program that simulates a poker game.

Currently I order the given 'hand' by this:

```
(defconstant order #(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A))

(defun sort< (el1 el2)
  (< (position el1 order)
     (position el2 order)))
```

I pass the 'hand' to a function which starts computing what hand it is.

```
(defun poker (hand)
  (defparameter sortedhand (sort hand 'sort< :key 'first))
  (if (and (equal (second(first sortedhand))(second(second sortedhand)))
           (equal (second(first sortedhand))(second(third sortedhand)))
           (equal (second(first sortedhand))(second(fourth sortedhand)))
           (equal (second(first sortedhand))(second(fifth sortedhand))))
      (print 't)
       (print 'f))
        (print sortedhand))
```

(Here I am checking if they are of the same suit)

The hand is given in this format:

```
(poker '((3 H)(2 H)(J H)(8 H)(5 H)))
```

Where 3 is the number and H is the suit (hearts).

For computing hands such as a Straight I must check whether the cards are consecutive values.

```
(poker '(8 H)(Q H)(9 H)(10 H)(J H))
```

For example is a Straight Flush.

Is there a way of doing this cleanly?
Is there any way I can use my constant order to achieve this?

Comment: DEFPARAMETER is for global variables. Don't use it inside DEFUN. Use LET.

Answer (score 2):

I would separate this into "straight" and "flush" predicates.

```
(defun straightp (hand)
  (let ((sorted-hand (mapcar #'first (sort (copy-tree hand) #'card<))))
    (every (lambda (card0 card1)
             (= 1 (card-diff card1 card0)))
           sorted-hand
           (rest sorted-hand))))

(defun flushp (hand)
  (apply #'suite= hand))

(defun straight-flush-p (hand)
  (and (straightp hand)
       (flushp hand)))
```

`Card<`, `card-diff` and `suite=` have rather obvious meaning:

```
(defconstant +card-values+
  #(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A))

(defun card-value (card)
  (position (first card) +card-values+))

(defun card-diff (card0 card1)
  (- (card-value card0) (card-value card1)))

(defun card< (&rest cards)
  (apply #'< (mapcar #'card-value cards)))

(defun suite= (&rest cards)
  (if (endp (rest cards))
      t
      (let ((card-suites (mapcar #'second cards)))
        (every #'eql card-suites (rest card-suites)))))
```

(Untested).